# How can I create a word consisting of sequence of letters which produce the word?

Tags: text

I found today at the web site of the Wolfram Programming Lab the following Code which can create a Pi symbol filled with the digits of Pi:

```
With[
 {
  pos = PixelValuePositions[
    Rasterize@
     Text@Style[Pi, 
       90, {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 70, 
        FontFamily -> "Source Serif Pro"}], 0]
  },
 Graphics[
  MapThread[Text, {Characters@ToString@N[Pi, Length[pos] - 1], pos}], 
  ImageSize -> 400]
 ]
```

[image]

**Question**:

How can I create a word consisting of the sequence of letters which produce the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided, that's easy! Of course I have to repeat the letters... Here I apply it right away to my favorite word along with my favorite font:

```
word = "Döp";
pos = PixelValuePositions[Rasterize@Style[word, 
  {FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"
  }], 0];    
chars = Characters@word;
charlist = chars[[Mod[Range[Length[pos]], Length[chars], 1]]];
g = Graphics[
  MapThread[
   Style[Text[#1, #2], FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 6, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"] &, {charlist, pos}], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Fixed typo in the "word"...

Comment: Great .. what is Döpp?

Comment: Erm... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2R8wl_6Wj4

Comment: Ah ... has something to do with football

Comment: in 96 I was in Prague in a Hotel and sitting in the entrance hall and you know whom I met ... this same guy and we talked a little bit about his crazy music

Comment: Must have been an interesting encouter. He seems to have quite a lot of self-confidence...